# OpenVPN through network manager does not resolve VPN hosts

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, openvpn

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have set up an OpenVPN connection with the Gnome network-manager. I have some domains that point to an ip address inside the vpn (e.g.: service.mydomanin.com points to 10.10.10.1). I want the vpn to work only for the traffic that goes to the ip addresses inside the vpn (e.g. 10.10.10.1), not all traffic: for this reason i have ticked the option "Use this connection only for resources on its network".

The problem is that the browser cannot resolve the domains pointing to the ip addresses inside the VPN with that option enabled (e.g. service.mydomain.com cannot be resolved). What am I doing wrong? That domain points to an ip address inside the vpn, why can't it be resolved?

Comment: This article may offer some help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55090/change-default-dns-on-openvpn-connect

Comment: I don't understand why the address is correctly resolved if untick the option "Use this connection only for resources on its network"

Comment: Could the problem be that the server behind service.mydomain.com is in the same network as the client trying to access it?